# Google Calendar event gets created with yesterday's date

Tags: java, timezone, google-calendar-api

I am creating Google Calendar Event with today as start date but its showing yesterday date in Calendar. E.g when I set 21 May 2015 as start date it but in Google Calendar it shows 20 May 2015. In code I set default timezone for start date of Event.

```
Date end1           =  new Date(date in yyyy-MM-dd format + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

com.google.api.client.util.DateTime endTime = new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(end1);

com.google.api.client.util.DateTime startTime = new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(date in yyyy-MM-dd format);

insertedEntry   =   updateCalanderEvent(event,request,emailsList,title,description,startTime,endTime ,calander.getCalanderId());


For Event in updateCalanderEvent() 

 myEvent.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime));
 myEvent.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime));

insertedEntry = myService.events().insert("primary", myEvent).setSendNotifications(true).setCalendarId(id.trim()).execute();
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @GwynHowell code added in Question.

Comment: Did you try your request in API explorer?https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert . I doubt its the issue with the first line of your code Date end1           =  new Date(date in yyyy-MM-dd format + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); I don't think you have to add + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Comment: @SGC yes i tried it with Api Explorer. + date code is for End date not for Start date.